# What is an alternative way to implement specialization of a base class constructor from a derived class?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, constructor, polymorphism

Given the following pseudocode classes, I wanted to specialize the constructor of the base class from the derived class.

```
class Entity
{
    public:
    Entity(float mass);

    virtual float PerformCalculation();
}

class SpecializedEntity : public Entity
{
    public:
    SpecializedEntity(float mass, float diameter);

    virtual float PerformCalculation() override;
}
```

Given that in the constructor of both classes, `PerformCalculation` needs to be called from the constructors of each class. In `PerformCalculation` there is an API call to my system that I need to make which allows me to specify the `diameter` parameter that only appears in `SpecializedEntity`. In the base class `Entity`, I just pass in `nullptr`.

Without modifying the huge amount of code in `PerformCalculation` what is a better way than the following approach?

```
class Entity
{
    public:
    Entity(float mass, bool initialize)
    {
        if (initialize) this->Initialize();
    }

    virtual void Initialize();
    virtual float PerformCalculation();
}

class SpecializedEntity : public Entity
{
    public:
    SpecializedEntity(float mass, float diameter) : diameter(diameter), Entity(mass, false)
    {
        this->Initialize();
    }

    virtual void Initialize() override;
    virtual float PerformCalculation() override;
}
```

Comment: Since `Initialize` is virtual, you don't need that `bool` and check in `Entity` ctor, your `SpecializedEntity::Initialize` will be called from `Entity` ctor fine. You don't need to call `Initialize` in `SpecializedEntity` ctor either. Do I miss sth?

Comment: @mentat No, there is no "virtual" call in the constructor because the vptr is not filled correctly before the first `{` of the child constructor.
E.g.: http://ideone.com/mna1Zv

Comment: Can you provide a complete minimal example ? I do not really understand your point.

Comment: @mentat A virtual method called from a base class constructor will not call an implementation in a derived class.

Comment: @Johan I didn't add a complete minimal example but can when I get home from work, since it's a bit involved to get the entire point across. I did my best in the short answer I provided in behalf of my coworker though. If you have specific questions, I'll try to answer them as clearly as possible though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to reply for my coworker since he saw this and told me an easy solution that is better, but still not ideal. It will also help to illustrate my point and leave room for a better answer.

The solution is for all derived classes to call `this->Initialize` from their constructor instead of allowing the base class to call it, since there shouldn't be any reason to use that base class.

```
class Entity
{
    protected:
    Entity(float mass)
    { }

    virtual void Initialize();

    public:
    virtual float PerformCalculation();
}

class SpecializedEntity : public Entity
{
    public:
    SpecializedEntity(float mass, float diameter) : Entity(mass)
    {
        this->Initialize();
    }

    virtual void PerformCalculation() override
    {
        // Do specific stuff here
    }
}
```

`PerformCalculation` is called from within `Initialize` and so it will use the more specialized `PerformCalculation` once it's called from the derived class.

Comment: Your `Entity` is not going be used directly, only as a base class; you even made its constructor protected. If that's what really needed, then no reason to have all these virtual functions. Simply do specialized calculations in `SpecializedEntity` constructor. But otherwise, when base `Entity` is a complete class itself, you'll need to do common calculations within `Entity` constructor.